# Poison unable to encode error message

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-poison

I am using phoenix as a JSON API. One of my models is as below which works well unless the unique_constraint check fails. When that happens I get the following error:

```
(Poison.EncodeError) unable to encode value: {"Email address is already registered", []}
```

**Model**:

```
defmodule MyApp.Registration do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:name, :email, :category]}
  schema "registrations" do
    field :name, :string
    field :category, :string
    field :email, :string

    timestamps
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(name email category), [])
    |> validate_length(:name, min: 1, max: 240)
    |> unique_constraint(:email, message: "Email address is already registered")
  end

end
```

**Controller**:

```
def create(conn, registration_params) do
  changeset = Registration.changeset(%Registration{}, registration_params)
  case  Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, _registration} ->
      # Success 
    {:error, error} ->
      conn
      |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
      |> render(MyApp.ErrorView, "generic.json", error: error)
  end
end
```

**View**:

```
def render("generic.json", error) do
  error
end
```

I think I probably need to somehow add the error messages to the `Poison.Encoder, only: []` list but I am unsure how to do that.

**Edit**

I should clarify that if I don't specify a custom error I still get the same error with the generic error message.

Comment: The errors are part of the Ecto.Changeset, not the model, so that looks strange. Could you provide the controller code and possible view code that renders the json?

Comment: @Svilen Added the controller and view code. I've tried a few ways of passing the changeset error to the json view but no joy so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is done automatically if you use `mix phoenix.gen.json` but the changeset errors need to be translated to json.

**View**:

```
def translate_errors(changeset) do
  Ecto.Changeset.traverse_errors(changeset, &translate_error/1)
end

def render("error.json", %{changeset: changeset}) do
  # When encoded, the changeset returns its errors
  # as a JSON object. So we just pass it forward.
  %{errors: translate_errors(changeset)}
end
```

**Controller**:

```
def create(conn, registration_params) do
  changeset = Registration.changeset(%Registration{}, registration_params)
  case  Repo.insert(changeset) do
    {:ok, _registration} ->
      # Success 
    {:error, changeset} ->
      conn
      |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
      |> render(MyApp.ErrorView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

Adding the `translate_error\1` function definition. This is contained within a module called `MyApp.ErrorHelpers` which is imported into the `view` function definition in either `web/my_app.ex` or `lib/my_app_web.ex` depending on your version of phoenix.

**`lib/my_app_web/views/error_helpers.ex`**:

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.ErrorHelpers do
  def translate_error({msg, opts}) do
    if count = opts[:count] do
      Gettext.dngettext(MyAppWeb.Gettext, "errors", msg, msg, count, opts)
    else
      Gettext.dgettext(MyAppWeb.Gettext, "errors", msg, opts)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have an idea where's defined the `translate_error/1` function?

Comment: @Jean-PierreBécotte I've updated the answer with the function definition.

Comment: Good job, @Razzildinho!